# Laravel 6.0 : Paginate completely ignored

Tags: php, laravel

I have a series of Models that work perfectly, with pagination.

However, one of them  **`Roles`** , corresponding to the "roles"  tables, works but completely skips pagination!

I have :

**Controller**

```
$roles = \DB::table('roles')->paginate(3);
// Or even
// $roles = Role::paginate(3);
return view('modules.roles.index', ['roles'=>$roles, 'rolecount'=>count($roles)  ] );
```

**View**

```
@foreach($roles as $role)

 XYZ 

@endforeach
```

However,

If I put  `{{ $roles->links() }}` in the  view, I get an error that

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist
```

Without the links, it outputs all the table records, not paginated!

What am I missing?

Comment: please post all the controller method

Comment: Do you maybe have a global `view()->share('roles' ...` that overrides this one?

Comment: just checked on my pc, it works perfectly, have you register something on your boot method with that key?

Comment: Pagination should work fine there is nothing wrong with your code. The bug comes from somewhere else

Comment: This is so interesting. 
@AlbertoSinigaglia I haven't registered anything at boot method

Comment: @PHPer just in case, try naming it something different than `roles` use `rolesList` for example, and pass that one to the view :)

Comment: on your view do {{ dd($roles) }} and than tell us what does it says

Comment: @nakov yes absolutely, but that doesn't resolve any problem, it just ignore that

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia It outputs all the records

Comment: and if you do ` dd($roles); ` just before the return on the controller method? what i'm interested in is the type of that variable

Comment: Update: I renamed the $roles variables and it worked. So something is registering the "roles" variable? can't think of anything but I think that's the new direction.

Comment: @PHPer as I said, look for `view()->share('roles' ..)` or `View::share('roles'..)` or any package that you use

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia so it seems like that did resolve the problem :)

Comment: It did.
@nakov I renamed the  variables and it worked. It seems there is another package (that I use ) with exactly the same variable.

Comment: check inside your Service folder inside all the register method if there is something with that key

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia  I found it. All good now. Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was another package defining the `roles` variable in its boot method. I renamed my variable to `rolesXYZ` and it worked fine.

In case it make help someone else, the exact error message was

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View: MYPATH\resources\views\ ...... \index.blade.php) 

Illuminate\Support\Collection::__call :103
MYPATH\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php:103
```